# SSRS subfolders in Visual Studio Report Server Project

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008.  Currently everything works find so long as I put all reports in the Reports folder of the Report Server Project in Visual Studio.

I attempted a work-around, which is to have multiple Report Server projects, each pointing to a different folder on the report server.  This has the side effect of not letting me reference the sub report from another project.

So, is there a way of referencing a sub-report from another project and still have the ability to preview?

Is there a way to get sub-folders in Report Server project?

Comment: Please vote on the issue on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/487106/allow-sub-folders-in-ssrs-projects

Answer (score 5):

it's not built-in to SSRS; but there is a workaround. Simply keep the reports under one project (to allow the reference) and manualy control the deployment location per report.

If you go this route, you may want to look automating this by creating a deployment script using rs.exe

[rs.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256617(SQL.80).aspx)

There are also some attempts at solving this on codeplex; but I haven't had a chance to take a look at this yet:
[rsbuild](http://rsbuild.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks.  For now I'm just keeping everything in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a long time since the question was first asked but, if anyone is looking for an answer these days like me here's what I was able to do.

Move all your reports into whatever folder structure you want.
Then edit your .rptproj file and find where your report item group is. It will look something like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="Report1.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Report2.rdl" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Just update those file names to be the full path like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="Folder1/Report1.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Folder2/Report2.rdl" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Reload your report project and it works.... (well it does for me!)
So far everything seems to work for me.

Comment: when you say it works what does that mean?  When you actually publish it to the report server do you actually have the result of your main projects Folder call it Project X and within Project X you now see two folders Folder1 and Folder2?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your SSRS Report to SubFolders do the following:

TargetReportFolder => /Institutional Statements/Monthly Statements

Institutional Statements being the master folder for your solution
and Monthly Statements being the child folder within them.